# How to fetch a user email and pass it to iFrame?

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, user, iframe

I need to be able to do next:  When a user fulfilling a form the user email needed to pass automatically. It says logged in user email automatically fetched.

How can I do that in SharePoint Online iFrame? I need that code for iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current user email using the client context. Below code is in JSOM.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
$("#your_iframe_id").contents().find("#your_control_id").val(currentUser.get_email());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<div>Current Logged User:
     <span id="userEmail"></span>
</div>
```

Note: you have to include jquery plug-in.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response. Do I need to add exactly this code as a script in the web part?After that it will work for the iFrame?

Comment: If you are working with Sharepoint hosted apps, this will do the trick.

Comment: Hello Arut, I added that script to Script Editor Web Part to the iFrame Web Part. I am able to get logged in user, but the information is not passing to the iFrame. How can I pass information to the iFrame?

Comment: You can search for an element from the iframe and you can set the value using jquery.

$("#iFrame_ID").contents().find("#some_Control_ID").val('your_value');

Comment: Sorry, how can I do that? I'm new learner. Maybe you can clarify little bit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: lets be clear about few things.. from where you have to push the data to iframe? what is there inside the iframe? can you update the question with the stuffs you have tried.

Comment: I would like to push a logged in users email to iFrame. iFrame consists name surname and email strings. A new user needs to write his/her name, surname and email address to the iFrame. But I would like to fetch for example loggedin user email ,name or surname which he/she using. But first would like to fetch email address. So how is it possible?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Where I need to include jquery plug-in?

Comment: just above the <script> tag, like below

`code` <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> `code`