# How to pass user information from Sharepoint to iframe embedded within

Tags: web-part, iframe, script-editor-webpart

We are trying to pass user information from SharePoint (user email) to an iframe embedded within it.  We have no problem getting the information to populate on the SharePoint page itself, but we can't get it to show within the iframe.

We did review [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216882/how-to-fetch-a-user-email-and-pass-it-to-iframe) which seems to be exactly on the mark; however, when we tried it, it does not work.  I note that this question is over 5 years old.

We are using SharePoint Online and we're using the Script Editor web part on a webpart page, not a Modern page.

Comment: You can get current user email using `_spPageContextInfo.userEmail` directly instead of using JSOM or REST, check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252579/get-user-logged-on-sharepoint-online/252599#252599). Do you have iframe element on same page OR are you trying to show the page in `iframe` element in other pages or dialog/popup?

Comment: The script and `iframe` are on the same page, and are written in the same script `webpart`. The `iframe` displays an external site.  We can get the user email to populate on the SharePoint page but we need to pass the email address into a page element within the `iframe`.